# Login function in separate file using RoboBrowser

Tags: python, python-requests, robobrowser

I am writing a program/script to retrieve some key information from Hoovers.com. I currently have 2 files. One is `hoovers5.py` (which contains, among other things, some classes) and the other is `main.py`.

`hoovers5.py`:

```
def testlogin():
    import hlogin # this is a file that contains my hoovers login credentials
    from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

    browser = RoboBrowser()
    login_url = "https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/login/login.html"
    browser.open(login_url)
    form = browser.get_form(id='loginForm')  # gets login form ID
    form['j_username'].value = hlogin._hname  # fills in hoovers login name
    form['j_password'].value = hlogin._hpass  # fills in hoovers password
    browser.submit_form(form)  # submits login
```

`main.py`:

```
import hoovers as hv5
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

hv5.testlogin()

browser = RoboBrowser()
browser.open('http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/company360/overview.htmlcompanyId=26082233')
print browser.parsed
```

I have tested this code numerous times and the login works if I run the login **WITHOUT** placing it into a function in my main file. It works in the sense that I can then execute the following and get the expected parsed value:

```
browser.open('http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/company360/overview.htmlcompanyId=621076715')
print browser.parsed
```

However, as soon as I create a function for the login, the login doesn't seem to...stick? Am I losing my session in my `hoovers5.py` file because I'm instantiating a new browser in `main.py`? How can I pass my "session" to my main script? I've tried creating an object called `browser2 = RoboBrowser()` and then opening the URL through that, but that also doesn't work.

Do I require cookies (And if, how EXACTLY would I go about this?) or do I need to return something in my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function creates a *new* `RoboBrowser()`, with separate state. It is as if you opened a new browser (not a new window or tab) and tried to use your login session there.

Share the `browser` object between the function and the rest of your code:

```
def testlogin(browser):
    import hlogin # this is a file that contains my hoovers login credentials

    login_url = "https://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/login/login.html"
    browser.open(login_url)
    form = browser.get_form(id='loginForm')  # gets login form ID
    form['j_username'].value = hlogin._hname  # fills in hoovers login name
    form['j_password'].value = hlogin._hpass  # fills in hoovers password
    browser.submit_form(form)  # submits login
```

and use this as:

```
import hoovers as hv5
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser()

hv5.testlogin(browser)

browser.open('http://subscriber.hoovers.com/H/company360/overview.htmlcompanyId=26082233')
print browser.parsed
```

Now you have *one* `browser` object, the login session is now stored in that object and you can continue to use that session for other URLs.

Comment: Oh this was so simple. Now I can use this in my class as well. Thank you so much. I will accept this as an answer, excellent!